# How does Flutter web handle manually typed URLs? I'm experiencing weird behaviours

Tags: flutter, url, flutter-web, address-bar, flutter-routes

I have a Flutter web project up and running.
Everything is working fine.

However, while testing new pages I just added, I noticed that although I can succesfully reach my new routes by clicking on the links that redirect to them, I sometimes cannot reach them if I type the URL manually in the address bar.

Sometimes, it just takes me back to the home route.
This seems to be happening in Chrome more than in Firefox.

I also noticed that after being unable to reach, for example, 'https://mysite/#newpage' if I click the address bar and I type a purposefully wrong URL by omitting the '#' (so 'https://mysite/newpage') and I hit enter, Flutter redirects me to the homepage but the url in the address bar changes to 'https://mysite/newpage#/'.
Now, if I manually correct the URL by deleting the trailng slash and moving the '#' right before 'newpage' (so the URL looks like this: 'https://mysite/#newpage'), it correctly takes me to the desired page despite it being the exact same correct but unreachable address previously typed.
This trick works 100% of the times.

As I mentioned before, links and redirects do not have this problem as they always take me to the correct page on the first attempt. This happens only when I type the URL manually.

So my question is:

How does Flutter handle URLs manually typed by the user? Is there anything special about it I need to be aware of? Or am I just missing something incredibly obvious?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using navigator 2?

Comment: I didn't specify anything about it in my project nor am I using any special class or method besides navigator.push(), navigator.pop() and onGenerateRoutes, so I guess I'm using navigator 1.0

Comment: you can give a try with navigator 2

Comment: I'll look in to that. Still, it seems really weird how it's behaving...

Comment: You can play with my [practice](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/navigator2/demo1.dart)

Comment: facing this as well. I am using onGenerateRoutes function but every time I go to some page by typing the URL in the browser, the app stays in the new page and automatically navigates to the home page